Programmatically creating a texture for a material in Unity
I'm trying to create a black texture in unity for a material, but it's not showing up
    // Create a black texture with a size of 800x600
    dotTexture = new Texture2D(800, 600);
    Color[] colors = dotTexture.GetPixels();
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
        colors[i] = Color.black;
    dotTexture.SetPixels(colors);
    dotTexture.Apply();

    dotMaterial.mainTexture = dotTexture; // Set the texture to the material

I can see the material and material's albedo texture. But this texture is not getting applied.
What am I doing wrong?

just to be sure - the matierla you are using is based on a shader that has a _MainTex property or [MainTexture] attribute? Otherwise you would have to go through SetTexture and explicitly provide the property ID

is the size relevant btw? If you just need anything black you can also just use e.g. a 2x2 texture ^^
